# German sentence - handwriting to translate to English

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting

[image]

Kindly help me to translale this. I found it on an envelop with a will.
Daniel

Comment: Is this family of yours? Do you have any way to narrow down and identify the names? As in "Dani" or "Doni", and potentially there's a name between what looks like "vom" and "soll". Could be "Vati" as written below, but there's that weird trailing bit... "Natinco"?! "Vatinco"?! Not any name I've ever heard.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this question is likely to be out of scope here (even if I'm not aware of a better section).

The handwriting is outright awful, so that without additional context information no doubtfree answer will be provided. I'm providing an answer nevertheless to allow modification by more experienced handwriting decoders.

My guess:

> Bitte Doni, das Hass [Haus?] xxx xxx soll für deine Tochter bleiben.

Translated: Please Doni [Dani? name, possibly of yourself?], the house [it looks more like Hass( hate), but this seems inappropriate], [next two or three words unreadable] shall remain for **your** [this word is double underscored] daughter.

**Update** included comments from @tofro and @Marakai:

The unrecognizable words are assumed to be *vom Vater immer*, so the full sentence reads:

> Bitte Doni, das Haus vom Vater immer soll für deine Tochter bleiben.

Translated:

> Please Doni, the house from father shall always remain for your daughter.

Comment: I pretty much doubt its "vorm Autokino" - The first words look like "vom Vater" to me

Comment: Oof, it looks like a bit of a mix between modern cursive and Sütterlin. What is that between supposed "vom Vati" and "soll"? "inco"?

Comment: @Marakai Could be a very badly written "immer" - So: "Bitte Doni, das Haus vom Vater immer soll für deine Tochter bleiben"

Comment: @tofro something like "imer"? It is bad grammar and spelling... possible! I had to decipher some old hand-written documents out of my late father's estate. If I didn't have at least some context and knowledge of the names, I'd probably be in a similar situation as the OP.

Comment: @Marakai Note handwriting double-"m" used to be done with a single "m" and a tiny line above it. My parents still used to write like that. And you could easily forget that line.

Comment: @tofro Ooooh, you're right. My grandparents did as well. I'd forgotten about that.